# Best way to connect 2 pins that are next to each other?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

The two pins are next to each other and they must be connect together.

How should I do that?

[image]

Just connect them together with a simple trace?

[image]

Or pour them together?

[image]

Comment: Does this really matter?

Comment: I would use the first option, but enable teardropping to remove the nasty right-angle copper lines. If teardropping is not viable, just draw on some extra track instead.

Comment: Can you place a zero ohm resistor between the 2?  This way it could be removed it needed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A large pour would allow more current (just like a wider trace), and would result in a larger solder blob. You probably need neither.

A simple trace between the middles of the pads might look like an accidental solder bridge if you don't know the circuit. To avoid such a misunderstanding, it might be a better idea to route the trace outside, if you can afford the space:

[image: two pads connected with loop]

Comment: I always use this idea if at all possible. Using this technique makes it easy to cut the trace in the case that the design has to change for some reason. On a recent design I had four I2C chips with their address pins connected like this to GND or VCC. It was necessary to replace one of the chips with a much larger capacity memory device and  it necessitated changing the address range of one of the other I2C parts. I was able to re-work the design very simply by cutting one of the loops and then adding a neat short loop of wire.

Comment: This is a very nice answer. I used to do as in this answer, but I haven't lately, because I forgot the reason for it.

Comment: If the space is a concern, it can also be tucked under the chip. Not ideal but better than having a blob of solder over two pins.

Answer (score 7):

In general it's best not to pour over pads (without thermal reliefs). It makes them harder to solder and desolder. The exception is high current stuff or stuff where you are using the tracks as heatsinks.

Going directly between pads with a track can lead people to think there is a manufacturing fault, especially if the soldermask on the track flakes off. Still it may be the best option on a very cramped board.

Usually a U shaped track coming out from the chip as CL suggests is the way to go.

I have been known to put a U shaped track under the chip, the downside of that approach is you have no way of cutting the track if you discover a design flaw.