# Why is this recommended in PCB layout: 2 leads between pads

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, layout, trace, pad

Why is the connection recommended as in the top picture?

[image]

[image]  [image]

Comment: The chosen layout depends on what part that is and what do those pins on the part do. Please add in the information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to connect 2 pins that are next to each other?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/224201/best-way-to-connect-2-pins-that-are-next-to-each-other)

Comment: @Armandas, do note that the page you linked asks about a large copper pour, which is not what İbrahim ATİKER asked.

Answer (score 1):

It allows the tracks to be cut etc during debugging or modifications.

I'd recommend it where possible and where practical to cut tracks. But the usefulness and value of it depends on what the boards are used for, the industry and situation of the company and so on.

[image]